# One material fades into another on model?

Tags: materials, node-editor, workflow

Is it possible to make the top of my model glossy, and have the glossiness fade into matte toward the bottom of the model? (Or any combination of surface variations, this is just an example) Thank you!

Comment: You need this in cycle or BI?

Comment: I am using cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If cycle it would be something like this
[image]

You use the the gradient as a factor between the 2 shaders.